# Error when calling multiple deletes: "Default changeset implementation allows only one operation"

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

The server is returning an exception when trying to delete multiple items. I put the OData call inside a `for` loop, but it returns the error below:

> ```json
> {
>   "code":"/IWBEP/CX_MGW_TECH_EXCEPTION",
>   "message":"Default changeset implementation allows only one operation",
>   "persistent":false,
>   "targets":"..."
> }
> ```

When I make the single line call, it is deleting correctly.

Here's the function I'm using to delete:

```js
onDelete(oEvent) {
  var that = this;
  var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
  oModel.setDeferredGroups(["group1"]);
  var oTable = this.getView().byId("LineItemsSmartTable").getTable();
  var oItems = oTable.getSelectedIndices();
  for (var i = 0; i < oItems.length; i++) {
    var j = oItems[i];
      var cpfKey = oTable.getContextByIndex(j).getProperty("Cpf");
      var sDelete = oModel.createKey("/CustomersSet", { Cpf: cpfKey });
      oModel.remove(sDelete, {
        success: function (oData, oResponse) {
          // ...
        },
        error: function (oError) {
          // ...
        },
      });
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This seems to be a common error many people are facing. What is the result of your research so far? What have you tried to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have two possibilities. The first one is the optimal solution (but takes time to implement). The second one is hacky.

### Implement `changeset_process`

With `changeset_process` all your requests will arrive in a single method. There are [plenty of tutorials](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/03/09/how-to-implement-odata-batch-processing-with-content-id-in-sap-gateway/) on how to implement it in the backend:

### Disable `useBatch`

If you send your delete requests in individual requests (and not bundled in one big batch request) the error should go away. You can change this setting right before sending (remember to toggle it right after sending) or on a global level in the manifest.json (where you declare your model)

```json
"dataSource": "mainService",
"settings": {
    "useBatch": false,
    ...
}
```

---

Maybe you also have this third option. I haven't tried it, just found it [in the docs](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel). If it works, it's also not optimal because requests will take much more time.

### Send your delete requests sequential (and not all at once).

By setting the parameter `sequentializeRequests` of your OData model to true, all requests will be sequentialized.

```json
"dataSource": "mainService",
"settings": {
    "sequentializeRequests": true,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, it still didn't work.

I included the suggestions in the manifest.json, however, it still gives an error.

I think it's important to mention that my data source type is Business Entity, with CDS.

Comment: There was a typo in my answer. useBatch has to be false and not true obviously. Still, the recommended approach (with CDS or without) is changeset_process.